# MongoDB - How to add 6 months to a specific field of all the documents

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

I have a collection called Posts and for each post I have a field called post_date like this:

```
"post_date" : ISODate("2020-02-10T00:00:00Z")
```

I want to update all documents by adding 6 months to the current "post_date" of each one. I searched for this but couldn't find a solution. Is there a way to do this in mongo shell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232356/mongodb-subtract-months-from-date-with-value-from-database

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
load('moment.js')
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
   db.collection.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id }, 
      { $set: { post_date: moment(doc.post_date).add(6, 'months').toDate() } }
   )
})
```